# Как расположить точки чтобы нарисовать прямоугольник

Tags: математика, геометрия

Как расположить точки чтобы вышел прямоугольник? Даны следующие точки: верхний левый угол(x1,y1) (994.738, 576.489) и нижний правый угол(x2, y2)(2937.913, 2289.481)

Comment: @ArniLand, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: Получается, мне нужно было на графике в программе нарисовать прямоугольник. Но стандартных методом для рисования прямоугольника в используемой мной библиотеке не было. Я вызвал метод для рисования полинома. Задал ему пять точек в таком формате  (x1, y1), (x1, y2), (x2, y2), (x2, y1), (x1, y1). Но вышел квадрат. Вот не знаю, что не так

Comment: @ArniLand, А ваш прямоугольник и является приблизительно квадратом: `x2 - x1 == 1943.175`, `y2 - y1 == 1712.992`, отношение сторон `19 : 17`.

Answer (score 2):

Если стороны должны быть параллельны осям, ваши вершины в порядке обхода: `(x1, y1)`, `(x1, y2)`, `(x2, y2)`, `(x2, y1)`.

Если стороны направлены куда угодно, у вас мало данных.

Answer (score 0):

Данных в вашей задаче достаточно, чтобы построить множество прямоугольников, а не один. Итак, есть левый верхний угол (х1, у1) и правый нижний угол (х2, у2). Соответственно, у нас есть отрезок - диагональ прямоугольника с координатами вершин (х1, у1) и (х2, у2). Середина этой диагонали, это середина прямоугольников и также центр окружности описанной вокруг множества прямоугольников. И вот выходит так, что можно прочертить множество вписанных в окружность углов, опирающихся на диагональ с вершинам х1,у1 и х2,у2. А есть теорема, что если вписанный в окружность угол опирается на диаметр окружности, значит он прямой. Вот и выходит, что вы можете прочертить множество прямоугольников.